# Как будет правильно создать список id. MySQL

Tags: mysql

Просьба помочь с выбором правильного варианта решения задачи. Нужно сделать список объектов, а именно id продуктов (Подобие оформленного заказа).
Я думал о "массиве", сделать nvarchar и писать туда id через пробел, думал о создании для каждого заказа своей таблицы, но боюсь это будет занимать ущербно много места (Или нет?), подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше и правильнее всего будет организовать это. Если есть более нормальные) способы, подскажите пожалуйста

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Одна запись - одно значение. Про "несколько значений в поле" - забудьте. Исключение - поле типа JSON, содержащее массив UNSIGNED INTEGER.

Comment: одна таблица: id заказа, id продукта. записей столько, сколько продуктов в заказе.

Comment: @Mike Оо, что-то сразу о подобном способе не надумал, спасибо большое